# how to enter the details of a ticket in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I need to create a ticket with its details. From visual studio I send a string list or string array to sql with the data to create the ticket. The amount of details is variable, my question is how to execute that x amount of details in sql server.

I am using visual studio 2017 and sql server 2008.

```
GO
create procedure newTicketWithDetails
@idProduct int,
as
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
BEGIN TRY

/*
idTicket is identity
idTicket and dateTicket are PK
*/

insert into Tickets(idTicket,dateTicket))
values (GETDATE());

insert into TicketsDetails(idTicket,dateTicket,idProduct) 
values(IDENT_CURRENT('Tickets'),GETDATE(),@idProduct); 


/*
...
...        x inserts here
...
*/

COMMIT TRANSACTION 

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT

END CATCH
```

Something like that is what I am trying to do.
How should I go through that array with ticket data or how should I send the details from visual studio?

Comment: Since you said that the "amount of details" is variable, you should probably create parameters and fill them out and send it to your stored proc.

Comment: "From visual studio I send a string list or string array to sql with the data to create the ticket." - Is this happening? Looking at your stored procedure, the only data being passed in is idProduct which is an integer.

Comment: This code is by way of example. My question is whether SQL server can receive a string array with all the query inside and read it, or if I have to do that tour in visual studio and from there make an insert for every detail. If it was only 1 or 2 details I can do it, my question is how to do it when the quantity is variable.

Comment: What is Visual Studio got to do with this question?  The question is a SQL Server question.

Comment: There's no such thing as array in SQL Server.

Comment: My idea is to send an array with the data for the insert. Another idea is to use a for each to read that array and in each iteration insert a row, using command.CommandText , but I don't know which is the best idea or the most correct one. I want to try to leave the transaction closer to the server than to the desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your parameters in an XML string as a single parameter. Then use XML parsing on the server side to get values out from the XML string and insert NON NULL ticket details in your table(s).

Refer: [XML as parameter in stored procedure (sql server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892692/xml-as-parameter-in-stored-procedure-sql-server)

This will save you a lot of code on the client side as you ever have to send a single parameter.